# parse array result from nodered and mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, node-red

How can I extract the value "Al Hidaya centre" from the mysql result below, I should generally get "Al Hidaya centre" as the result from the mysql query, however I am getting this mambo jumbo with the result as well.

i have tried the following **msg.payload[3]** but this only gives me

> [ { "device_name": "Al Hidaya centre" } ]

**mysql result in nodered mysql node:**

> { "fieldCount": 0, "affectedRows": 0, "insertId": 0, "serverStatus":
>   10, "warningCount": 0, "message": "", "protocol41": true,
>   "changedRows": 0 }, { "fieldCount": 0, "affectedRows": 0, "insertId":
>   0, "serverStatus": 10, "warningCount": 0, "message": "", "protocol41":
>   true, "changedRows": 0 }, { "fieldCount": 0, "affectedRows": 0,
>   "insertId": 0, "serverStatus": 10, "warningCount": 0, "message":
>   "\u0012Statement prepared", "protocol41": true, "changedRows": 0 }, [
>   { "device_name": "Al Hidaya centre" } ], { "fieldCount": 0,
>   "affectedRows": 0, "insertId": 0, "serverStatus": 2, "warningCount":
>   0, "message": "", "protocol41": true, "changedRows": 0 } ]

**and the mysql query:**

```
 SET @var_name =  (SELECT settings_table FROM prayertime_table where id = 1);   SET @s = concat('select device_name from ', @var_name) ;  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;  EXECUTE stmt1;  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: Can you try msg.payload[3]["device_name"]

Comment: not working, msg.payload[3]["device_name"] : undefined
(undefined)

Comment: The posted result is not valid JSON, can you please try pasting the correct output?